# Jmeter JMS Publisher Issue

Tags: jmeter, jms-topic

I am trying pushing messgae through jmeter JMS publisher in solace queue. But I am getting below error.
Error:
javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection - internal error (403: Client Username Is Shutdown)

Also, please confirm on "Destination" field. 
Currently I am using "Topic JNDI" Value in Destination.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Solace documentation](https://docs.solace.com/Features/Client-Authorization.htm):

> After the client is bound to a client username account in the specified Message VPN, the message broker checks whether that client username account is enabled or not. **If the client username account is not enabled, the client is disconnected. (The response “403 Client Username Is Shutdown” is sent before disconnecting.)**

So I would recommend double-checking your [username and the way you're setting it](https://docs.solace.com/Solace-JMS-API/JNDI-Connection-Properti.htm#jms_properties_39190069_302563), it can be one of the following approaches (from highest priority to lowest):

- via the Java System Property
- via JNDI property
- embedded in the URL

Check out [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) to learn more on message brokers/queues/topics load testing concept.